# Why my WebMethod always returns JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

First my apologies if this is a noob question, it's not my area.

I have a WebMethod, which return **String** (string table=""). But the Ajax return function 
always see that as an JSON Object looks like `{"d":{...}}`. My Question is WHY 
I get a JSON back, even though my Ajax is expecting "text" ?

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string TestAjax(string val)
{
    string sSql = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GetMiToSend"];
    sSql = sSql.Replace("$Company$", val);
    string table = "";
    try
    {
        DbCommand command = m_connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sSql;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        DbDataReader oDataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        if (oDataReader != null)
        {
            count = oDataReader.FieldCount;
        }
        table = "<table>";
        while (oDataReader.Read())
        {
            table += "<tr>";
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                table += "<td>" + oDataReader.GetValue(i) + "</td>";
            }
            table += "</tr>";
        }
        table += "</table>";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return table;
}
```

My Ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/TestAjax") %>',
    data: JSON.stringify(toSend),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $('div#container div#content').html(data.d).show(1000);
        $('div#container div#showContent').hide();
        $('div#container div#content').addClass('rwd-table');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your bug is in your server code, not javascript. But you haven't mentioned what language your server code is written in (it definitely is not javascript)

Comment: That's C# .. Sorry . But Where's the bug ? I create a string (which suppose to used as HTML on the client side") and returns it .

Comment: I can ONLY assume the bug is in C# because there is no bug in your javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't return a `string` from a `WebMethod`. I tried without success to confirm my assertion. So change your code to return a `json` instead of a `string`.

[MS Developer Network: How to: Use the WebMethod Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Attaching the WebMethod attribute to a Public method indicates that you want the method exposed as part of the XML Web service.

Return a `json` in your `WebMehod`:

```
List<object> jsonObject = new List<object>();

jsonObject.Add(new
{
    htmlTable = table
});

return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(jsonObject);
```

Change your `ajax` to return a `json`:

```
dataType: "json"
```

Then access your json object and your html table:

```
var dataParsed = $.parseJSON(data.d);
var htmlTable = dataParsed[0].htmlTable;
// Do your actions with your htmlTable. Append to an element or other action.
```